# Launch activities with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

So I'm using Sherlock library to show ActionBar(that needs it in 4.2 and earlier) and a Navigation tab bar. I want to show some Activity content in tab1 and other activity in tab2 when pressing it. Is that possible with Sherlock library? If not please provide me some other solutions.

```
public class TabNavigation extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private TextView mSelected;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.tab_navigation);
        mSelected = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
            tab.setText("Tab " + i);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
        //LAUNCH ACTIVITIES HERE! POSSIBLE?
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot, change your activity to  show to a Fragment.

Comment: Any possible guide please? This is my first time using that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible with Sherlock library?

No.

> If not please provide me some other solutions.

Use fragments for your tabs. Or, otherwise modify the UI of your existing activity. Activities-in-tabs has been deprecated for nearly two years.

Comment: Moving an Activity to Fragment is that possible? flexible?

Comment: @Anis: Please can you provide some links of how moving from an Activity class to a Fragment one. I can't find some useful ones.

Comment: can you post your activity class ?